# Send Ajax post request and retrieve the inserted id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to submit a form which will insert data into a mysql database which is working fine. I then would like to return the id of the new inserted row (id auto increment in mysql table) as I want to open up a modal once the form is submitted so I can provide a link which includes id as a parameter in the url.

To send the data for the form I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitForm").click(function(){

var string = $('#commentForm').serialize();

// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SubmitData.php",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
        //alert(result);
        }
    });
});
});
```

The SubmitData.php file then inserts the form data into the database.

In the SubmitData.php I can create a variable to pick up the id of the newly inserted row like
`$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`

Is there a way I can return the $last_id from the SubmitData.php file within the same function?

Comment: yes, you add the id to the response from PHP, and there it is, in the success callback `result` argument

Comment: Just echo that id on the page and you will get that in result in **success** function

Comment: in your php, simply call `echo $last_id; exit;` then in your ajax, `result` will be the id :)

Comment: could you please write your php function here, at which you are sending the request

Comment: @vishal why? it wont change the process

Comment: Perfect thanks! @DelightedD0D it worked. So simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes return from SubmitData.php the id using the following echo:

```
echo json_encode(['id'=>$last_id]);
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitForm").click(function(){

var string = $('#commentForm').serialize();

// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SubmitData.php",
        data: string,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result){
          alert(result.id);//this will alert you the last_id

        }
    });

});

});
```

Comment: This also works and would be great if there was a lot of data returned but as it's only 1 id then is there really a need to return as json?

Comment: its not necessary but will give a little structure to your code, you should return a status code first, what happens if the query doesn't find results you need to tell the user that the query didn't return result

Answer (score 2):

print last id in that php file

```
echo $last_id;
```

get that in ajax success function

```
success: function(result){
        alert(result);

}
```